# Is there a good way to do conditional select on a dask dataframe for many conditions?

Tags: python, dask

I'm switching from Pandas to Dask and want to do conditional select on a dataframe. I'd like to provide a list of conditions, preferably as boolean arrays/series and would then get a dataframe with all these conditions applied.

In Pandas, I just did np.all([BoolSeries1, BoolSeries2,...]) and applied the result to the dataframe.

```py
import dask.array as da
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df  = pd.DataFrame({'A' : np.random.rand(1000) , 'B': np.random.rand(1000), 'C' : np.random.rand(1000) })
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10)

cuts = [(ddf['A'] > 0.4), (ddf['B'] < 0.4)]
bool_ar = da.all(da.asarray([cut.compute() for cut in cuts]),axis=0).compute()
ddf = ddf.loc[bool_ar.to_dask_dataframe()]['C']
```

This works but is quite slow because I have to call `.compute()` twice.

I feel like there must be some better way to solve this, converting first to an array and then back to a dataframe feels really clunky.

Comment: you can use ```.compute() ``` and use the same condition that it's used in pandas

Comment: @LarissaTeixeira: But then I would have to keep the whole dataframe in memory, right? Even after applying my selection criteria it's quite large so I would like to avoid that. I added a `.compute()` to the end of the da.all() but then the selection fails with `'Cannot index with list against unknown division'`

Comment: It seems like the unknown divisions are the problem, I guess I should change that. Still doesn't fix the clunkyness of the solution in general.

Comment: when you use ```.compute()``` you dont keep all dataframe in memory. I was reading about this yesterday, dask dataframe works like chunks.

Comment: Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)? for your real case?

Comment: This works for me `ddf = ddf[(ddf['A']>0.4) & (ddf['B']<0.4)]["C"]` no need to use `dask.array`.

Comment: @rpanai: Unfortunately I'm not able to produce a real mcve as I don't know how to force dask dataframes to have `ddf.known_divisions = False`. My real case has this though as I'm loading from csv.

Comment: @rpanai: Your example (`ddf = ddf[(ddf['A']>0.4) & (ddf['B']<0.4)]["C"]`) works for me too but I can't extend it to an arbitrary amount of conditions. I'd like to provide these conditions as a list and to apply all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to call `.compute` prematurely.  This brings things out of Dask space and back into numpy/pandas, which makes it hard to align things again, and is also inefficient, instead I think that you're looking for the `&` operator

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({'A' : np.random.rand(1000) , 'B': np.random.rand(1000), 'C' : np.random.rand(1000) })
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10)

df2 = df[(ddf['A'] > 0.4) & (ddf['B'] < 0.4)]
```

Every time you switch between dask dataframe and dask array or dask and numpy/pandas you introduce more complexity.  It's best to stay within one system if you can.  Things will be simpler.

You can extend this to an arbitrary number of conditions with a for loop.

```
conditions = [...]

cond = conditions[0]

for c in conditions[:1]:
    cond = cond & c
```

Comment: Your example (ddf = ddf[(ddf['A']>0.4) & (ddf['B']<0.4)]) works  but I can't extend it to an arbitrary amount of conditions. I'd like to provide these conditions as a list and to apply all of them.

Comment: Of course, I don't know why I didn't think of a for loop. I guess I was trying to replicate my solution from numpy which was using np.all(). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I've solved it.

```
import dask.array as da
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import operator
from functools import reduce

df  = pd.DataFrame({'A' : np.random.rand(1000) , 'B': np.random.rand(1000), 'C' : np.random.rand(1000) })
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10)

cuts = [(ddf['A'] > 0.4), (ddf['B'] < 0.4)]

bool_arr = reduce(operator.and_, cuts)
ddf = ddf.loc[bool_arr]['C']
```

Using reduce and the and_ from the operator module solve my problem. Thanks for the help, everybody!